# Using terminal command to search through files for a specific string within a python script

Tags: python, file, terminal

I have a parent directory, and I'd like to go through that directory and grab each file with a specific string for editing in python. I have been using `grep -r 'string' filepath` in terminal, but I want to be able to do everything using python. I'm hoping to get all the files into an array and go through each of them to edit them.

Is there a way to do this by only running a python script?

Comment: You can also feed `grep` an array of files: like `grep 'pattern' file1 file2 file3`.

Comment: or `grep "pattern" file*`. If you choose python, I suggest that you perform the grep operation natively using python and string/regex features so you don't depend on `grep` which is not installed by default on windows for instance, you don't handle subprocess output... only advantages.

Comment: But you want to do this in a terminal or in a python script? It's not clear from the title.

Comment: I want to do this in a python script. The goal is to find then mass edit those files.

Answer (score 1):

**changing current folder to parent**

```
import os    
os.chdir("..")
```

**changing folder**

```
import os
os.chdir(dir_of_your_choice)
```

**finding files with a rule in the current folder**

```
import glob
import os
current_dir = os.getcwd()
for f in glob.glob('*string*'):
    do_things(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
#sourceFolder is the folder you're going to be looking inside for backslashes are a special character in python so they're escaped as double backslashes
sourceFolder = "C:\\FolderBeingSearched\\"

myFiles = []

# Find all files in the directory
for file in os.listdir(sourceFolder):
    myFiles.append(file)

#open them for editing
for file in myFiles:
    try:
        open(sourceFolder + file,'r')
    except:
        continue 

    #run whatever code you need to do on each open file here
    print("opened %s" % file)
```

EDIT: If you want to separate all files that contain a string (this just prints the list at the end currently):

```
import os
#sourceFolder is the folder you're going to be looking inside for backslashes are a special character in python so they're escaped as double backslashes
sourceFolder = "C:\\FolderBeingSearched\\"

myFiles = []
filesContainString = []
stringsImLookingFor = ['first','second']
# Find all files in the directory
for file in os.listdir(sourceFolder):
    myFiles.append(file)

#open them for editing
for file in myFiles:

    looking = sourceFolder + file

    try:
        open(looking,'r')        
    except:
        continue 

    print("opened %s" % file)

    found = 0
    with open(looking,encoding="latin1") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            for x in stringsImLookingFor:
                if line.find(x) != -1:
                    #do whatever you need to do to the file or add it to a list like I am
                    filesContainString.append(file)
                    found = 1
                    break
            if found:
                break

print(filesContainString)
```

Comment: Using this, how would you separate all the files from the files containing a specific string?